# Loop that displays the first post of every available custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-post-type-archives

Is it possible to create a loop that goes through all the available custom post types without statically defining what those custom post types are, and then displaying the featured image of the first post for each of those custom post types?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
// grab all public post types
$post_types = get_post_types( array('public' => true), 'names' );

// loops through each post type
foreach( $post_types as $type ) {

    // setup the query
    $query_args = array(
        'post_type' => $type,
        'posts_per_page' => 1
    );

    // perform the query
    $items = get_posts( $query_args );

    // check if we have found anything
    if( $items ) {

        // loop through the items
        foreach( $items as $item ) {

            // show the post thumbnail
            echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $item->ID, 'thumbnail' );

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: That's amazing, thank you so much Pippin! One tiny nitpick, there's a comma missing after the first property of the $query_args array. Apart from that, brilliant solution.

Comment: Fixed the missing comma.

Comment: One more question: is it possible to exclude certain post types from this query?

Comment: @Squrler See my addition to Pippins answer below. In any case - if you want to exclude/include custom post types - you'll have to manually unset the from the `$post_types` array or filter them out with an `foreach()` and `! in_array()` or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to @Pippin answer:

It is even possible to use a single query, with a slightly different syntax.

```
// Get all post types
$post_types = get_post_types( 
     array( 
         'public'       => true
         // Avoid attachments - those aren't shown in the admin menu
        ,'show_in_menu' => true 
     )
    ,'names'
);

// Get rid of unwanted post types
// Use the array to add your unwanted post types
foreach ( array( 'some_unwanted_post_type', 'another_one' ) as $not_me )
    in_array( $not_me, $post_types ) AND unset( $post_types[ $not_me ] );

// Group by filter
add_filter( 'posts_groupby', 'wpse57806_posts_groupby', 20 );

// Query posts - Two options for post_types
$items = get_posts( array(
     'post_type'      => $post_types
    // ... or ...
    # 'post_type'       => 'any' // every post type, but not attachments
    ,'posts_per_page' => count( $post_types )
) );

// Call the thumbnail
foreach ( $items as $item )
    echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $item->ID, 'thumbnail' );
```

#### Edit

You'll need a small callback function to make the edit work:

```
function wpse57806_posts_groupby()
{
    // only needed once - better kept in here
    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );

    return 'post_type';
}
```

Comment: That won't output one of each type though, no? If there are 5 types, but the 5 most recent posts are all of one type, you'll get 5 of that single type.

Comment: @Milo `'orderby' => 'post_type'` _should_ do the trick. I just have no setup with 5 different post types + 50 posts available.

Comment: @Milo No, you're right. That will make it even worth, as we'd get `5` of the first `post_type`. Have to reconsider my answer. Guess it won't work without filtering the query... and adding something like a `DISTINCT` to it.

Comment: @Milo I guess I found a solution, that should work seamlessly.